# What computational methods are available for predicting nanoparticle structure?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, computational-chemistry, software, molecular-dynamics

I'm a quantum chemist, and nearly every system I've ever cared about has been studied by DFT. However, I am currently trying to model the surface interactions on a nanoparticle around 100 nm in diameter. I know the composition of the nanoparticle, but I do not know which atoms are at the surface versus in the core. It's too large to really be reasonable in my regular DFT packages. Any ideas on where to start?

Comment: For big nanoparticles, you're probably looking at something like [ReaxFF](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpcc.5b01597). For 100 nm, if this is a million or more atoms, classical MD is not really there. You would need to perform finite element analysis and lose all atomistic information.

Comment: Much appreciated @pentavalentcarbon! I think that's what I've been leaning toward and avoiding. Looks like I can't avoid it anymore...

Comment: I agree with the ReaxFF comment. However, are you sure that you need to model surface interactions on a 100 nm NP? I can't think of many reasons why you'd need to look at a 100 nm surface for a surface interaction (but it's not my work after all!). Why would a periodic cell containing dozens, or even hundreds, of atoms not be sufficient?

Comment: @Argon in this case, I am looking at a hetero-nanoparticle and the surface interactions are the second half of a project plan. Initially, I just need to figure out what atoms preferentially appear at the surface. From there, I can simplify my system and look at smaller sections of the surface.

Comment: @AlyChem Depending on the problem at hand, perhaps you can get away with a smaller cross-section of the NP surface by doing an ab initio thermodynamic approach to predict the most favorable surface structures (e.g. see here http://www.diss.fu-berlin.de/diss/servlets/MCRFileNodeServlet/FUDISS_derivate_000000002356/04_chap4.pdf?hosts or check out Chapter 7 of David Sholl's DFT text).